# Developed merge sort for big arrays using pthread library in C

Tags: c, algorithm, pthreads

I was wanted in my homework to develop a parallel merge sort program according to the algorithm shown in the following figure, for any array size `N=2^M` (20 <= M <= 28) and any `K` (1 <= K <= 5). The figure shows an example for `K=3`.

I must write the program in C (not C++) using Linux `pthread` library.

And I must use `mergesort` algorithm for the sort modules in the figure.

Both M and K are input command line arguments to the `main()` function, e.g.,

```
./a.out  20  3
```

[image]

**I wrote the following program so far:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define REP 3
#define MAX 50

//K
unsigned int K;

//input array
int* values;
unsigned int N;

//sorted array
int* sorted;

using namespace std;

//input of thread functions. position of the array for that thread.
typedef struct Arr {
   int low;
   int high;
} ArrayIndex;


void fillarray(int* data, unsigned int N)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        data[i] = rand();
}



void *pms(void *a)
{
        ArrayIndex *pa = (ArrayIndex *)a;
        partition (values, pa->low,pa->high);
        return 0;
}



void partition(int *arr,int low,int high){

    int mid;
    if(low<high){
         mid=(low+high)/2;
         partition(arr,low,mid);
         partition(arr,mid+1,high);
         mergeSort(arr,low,mid,high);
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high){

    int i,m,k,l,temp[MAX];

    l=low;
    i=low;
    m=mid+1;

    while((l<=mid)&&(m<=high)){

         if(arr[l]<=arr[m]){
             temp[i]=arr[l];
             l++;
         }
         else{
             temp[i]=arr[m];
             m++;
         }
         i++;
    }

    if(l>mid){
         for(k=m;k<=high;k++){
             temp[i]=arr[k];
             i++;
         }
    }
    else{
         for(k=l;k<=mid;k++){
             temp[i]=arr[k];
             i++;
         }
    }

    for(k=low;k<=high;k++){
         arr[k]=temp[k];
    }
}

void check(){

    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= N-2; i++)
        if (sorted[i] > sorted[i+1]) {
            printf("ERROR %d %d %d", i, sorted[i], sorted[i+1]);
            return;
        }

    printf("CORRECT\n");
}



int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int thread;
    // N = 2 ^ M
    long M = stol(argv[1]);
    N = (unsigned int) pow (2.0, M);

    // K
    K = (unsigned int) stoi(argv[2]) ;
    //test N and K:
    printf("N=%d K=%d\n", N, K);

    int thread_count = pow(2 ,K);
    ArrayIndex ai[thread_count];

    int i=0;
    for(i =0; i <thread_count; i++)
    {
        ai[i].low = i * (N / thread_count);
        ai[i].high = (i + 1) * (N / thread_count);
    }


    pthread_t* thread_handles;
    thread_handles = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(pthread_t));


    srand(time(0));

    time_t t1, t2;
    double dt; //t2-t1
    double tavg=0.0;

    //input array
    values = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * N );

    int r; 
    for (r = 0; r < REP; r++)
    {
        //fill in the input array with random numbers
        fillarray(values, N);

        //t1
        t1 = time(0);

        //sort the array
        //parallel merge sort 


        thread=0;

        for(thread; thread<thread_count; thread++)
        {
            pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, pms, &ai[thread]);
        }
        thread=0;
        for(thread=0; thread<thread_count; thread++)
        {
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
        }


        //t2
            t2 = time(0);

        //t2-t1
            dt = t2 - t1;

        //average time
            tavg += (dt / REP);

        //check for correctness
            check();
    }

    printf ( "%g seconds\n", tavg );

    return 0;
}
```

**Am I in a correct way so far?**

**This is output when I want to compile my program :**

```
user@sharifvm:~/the04a$ gcc -O2 -pthread  msort.c -lm
msort.c:45:6: warning: conflicting types for âpartitionâ [enabled by default]
 void partition(int *arr,int low,int high){
      ^
msort.c:39:3: note: previous implicit declaration of âpartitionâ was here
   partition (values, pa->low,pa->high);
   ^
msort.c:56:6: warning: conflicting types for âmergeSortâ [enabled by default]
 void mergeSort(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high){
      ^
msort.c:52:10: note: previous implicit declaration of âmergeSortâ was here
          mergeSort(arr,low,mid,high);
          ^
/tmp/ccCKc6qF.o: In function `main':
msort.c:(.text.startup+0x1e): undefined reference to `stol'
msort.c:(.text.startup+0x62): undefined reference to `stoi'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
user@sharifvm:~/the04a$
```

Whats wrong about `stol` and `stoi` functions?

*Please check the algorithm also. I have only 3 hours to finish this homeword :(*

**What can I do to make it efficient in memory and speed?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but did not you ask the same question just sometime back?

Comment: `using namespace std;` is C++, not C

Comment: @SouravGhosh Are you still here! yes, I edit the question a lot, and so I receive another error.

Comment: Fix the warnings by moving function `merge_sort` above all functions and move the `partition` function before the `pms` function. The errors are telling that the compiler couldn't find a function named `stoi`. Perhaps you need `atol` instead of `stoi` and `atoi` instead of `stoi`?

Comment: @CoolGuy both `stoi` and `stol` are undefined. I changed `stoi` to `stol`. error changed to `undefined reference to "stol"`

Comment: @User1-St Try `atoi`/`atol`.

Comment: @User1-St , I did not tell to change `stoi` to `stol`. I told to change `stoi` to `atoi` and `stol` to `atol`.

Comment: @szczurcio no, those are not typos. I was meant string to int. but it seems that `atoi`  is work also! I don't know why stoi doesn't worked in my case!

Comment: @User1-St Well, not "also", but "only". `atoi` etc are supposed to stand for "ASCII to int" (I suppose). There's no `stoi` in the standard library.

Comment: @User1-St , Sorry. I don't know how mergesort works. If your code works as expected, considering posting it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @szczurcio Oops! I don't want convert ascii to int! I want to receive `main` arguments as int. what shall I do?

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you anyway. :)  how can I receive main argument as string value and not as their Ascii values?

Comment: @User1-St , "_I want to receive main arguments as int_" -- That's exactly want `atoi` does,i.e, converts a string containing a number to an integer(`int`).

Comment: @User1-St , "_how can I receive main argument as string value and not as their Ascii values?_" -- Simply remove the `atoi` and stuff?

Comment: @CoolGuy - please don't suggest that people take their code to Code Review when the code does not even compile. It just leads to a double-disappointment when it is closed there, and then that community is the one that is made to clean up the mess.

Comment: @CoolGuy You are right. `atoi` worked in my case. I call the program like `./a.out 2 3` and it prints `N=4 K=3` (as we expected.) But I receive `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`  in the next line.

Comment: @User1-St , Does the code compile with the `using namespace std;`? If so, you are compiling in C++, not C.

Comment: @CoolGuy No, I remove that line. thank you for your help and considerations. May I ask you to post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

This should be in comment but, I don't have much reputation to leave a comment.

You can't take command line arguments directly as `int`. But you can convert string to integer using the following statement -

`int N = (int) strtol(M,(char **)NULL,10);`

add `string.h` library